# UCMA with UserApplication instance

Tags: visual-studio, lync, ucma

I am super new to using UCMA and tried using [this](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2013/03/creating-ucma-applications-with-a-userapplication-instance-example-sending-ims/) example to learn how to create a UCMA application using a User Application endpoint(can't use ApplicationEndpoint).

However, I am getting this error:

`An exception of type 'Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.TlsFailureException' occurred in Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.dll but was not handled in user code`

`Additional information: The target principal name is incorrect`

The error is popping up on line 54 on the sample code on the link. The code is `_endpoint.EndEstablish(ar);`

Comment: First, make sure the app is running as administrator.  If you are running from VS, then make sure VS is running as administrator.
Second, double check all your "sipaddress" and "domain" are correct for your Lync setup.

Comment: Already did both of those things.

Comment: If you google "The target principal name is incorrect", it seems to be a AD error.  Which would point to a AD problem.  On the same machine, can you use the same login within a Lync Client?   Do you get the same problem?